# Show that $\chi_A$ is Riemann-integrable iff $A$ has content.

Tags: calculus, analysis

I have a problem that says:

Let $A \subset R^n$ be a bounded set and define the
indicator function of $A$

$\chi_A(x) =
  \begin{cases}
    1 & \text{if } x \in A \,, \\
    0 & \text{if } x \notin A \,.
  \end{cases}$

Show that $\chi_A$ is Riemann-integrable iff $A$ has
content.

I am trying to prove both directions:
If A has content (i.e the limits limρ→0
S(Aρ), limρ→0 S(Bρ) both exist and are equal, where Aρ is the interior of the set and B is the union of interior and boundary) then  $\chi_A$ is Riemann-integrable. I was thinking of doing this by using a proof by contraposition: If A doesn't have content, then $\chi_A$ is not Riemann-integrable. However, I am stuck at the definition of "content" as I don't know how to connect the idea of having "content" and Reimann integrable. As for the other direction, I was thinking of using the definition of Reimann integrability (with epsilon ) and proceeding to show that it has content!

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Comment: What is content? Anyways, it should be clear how to proceed. Show the boundary of A is the set of discontinuities. Conclude

Comment: the content is the length, the area, and the volume, respectively to the dimension

Comment: @AndrewZhang If I show that the boundary of A is the set of discontinuities, does that mean that the boundary of A is 0, and if yes how can I formally do that?

Comment: A function is riemann integrable if and only if its set of discontinuities has Lebesgue measure zero. Once you show the set of discontinuities of the indicator function is the set boundary, you can conclude.

Comment: @AndrewZhang what about the other direction of the proof?

Comment: The indicator function is Riemann integrable if and only if its set of discontinuities has Lebesgue measure zero. The set of discontinuities is the boundary. Hence it’s Riemann integrable if and only if the boundary has Lebesgue measure zero.